# Is it ok to have travel insurance from more than one company?

Tags: legal, insurance, travel-insurance-claim

I currently own two credit cards in different countries (my country of residence and my country where I am a citizen of) and they both have free travel insurance included through different insurance companies.

Could I run into any problems while trying to make a claim?

I know that I can't claim the same problem with both of them, but I also heard that the process could get long and complicated, because one company may try to get a part of the payout from the other company, is that true?

Comment: I think that’s typically true overall, but it might help you get a better answer if you specified the card companies/insurers.

Comment: If your claim relates to a product or service obtained using one of the cards it would make sense to make the claim from that one.

Comment: How would they even know that you have another insurance covering this? There are many cases were insurers want to push the problem to another one (e.g. renter / landlord / building insurance, or your insurance trying to recover from the insurer of the person/company who caused the problem), but I don't quite see it in this instance.

Comment: Also note that some (many? most?) of the insurances bundled with credit cards only kick in if you actually paid for your trip using that card (though it depends on what exactly the problem is and what "paying for your trip" means).

Comment: @jcaron credit card companies share data all the time (as do banks). And of course they're 2 cards, but they may e.g. both be Mastercard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have multiple insurances covering the same thing, you can apply to any single of these insurances to get your damages covered, and they have to cover it in the same way as if they were your only insurers.

They may try to recover money from the other insurance, but (1) that doesn't affect you, and (2) the other insurance has no reason to give the first insurance any money, since there is no contract between them. And (3) a significant part of the cost for an insurance claim is *handling* the claim. You are not the only person with two insurances, and someone will claim at the other insurance, so it's cheapest for all insurances to just pay without causing each other extra work and cost.

It's just bad luck / good luck for the insurance if you ask the insurance to pay / ask another insurance to pay.

Comment: However, it is possible that *your* contract with Insurer B obligates you to attempt to recover from any other policy before claiming whatever's left from B.  That does, in effect, let B recover from A, with you as the middleman, even though there is no contract between them.  If they both have such a clause, then you are probably stuck dealing with both.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, credit card travel insurance only covers travel that you *pay* for - completely - with that credit card.
As you can only 'pay completely' with one card, the problem doesn't really exist.